# Can't put image filed to Amazon s3 in Python Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

I want to upload an image file on Flask + Amazon s3 but this error occurs:

[image]

Actually I have s3 to be in public. But after uploading the image, this can't get...

My code:

```py
import os

import io
import boto3
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, current_app
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in current_app.config["ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"]

def uploads_file(request):
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        s3_bucket = current_app.config['S3_BUCKET']
        s3_dir = current_app.config['S3_DIR']
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'us-west-1')
        response = s3.put_object(
            Body = io.BufferedReader(file).read(),
            Bucket = s3_bucket,
            Key = f'{s3_dir}/{filename}'
        )
        return filename
```

I have added `app/.aws/credentials`.

```
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: you will need some aws credentials to do this ... i dont think uploads can be public ... you need a file in `~/.aws/credentials` I think that provides the 2 identity tokens

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for your advice. I have added ~/.aws/credentials. But it is not working still. Should I have to define aws.client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass credentials when you create s3 client. Something like this should work:

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=access_secret,
    region_name='us-west-1',
)

with open(path, 'rb') as src:
    client.put_object(
        ACL='public-read',
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=filename,
        Body=src
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have successfully built it :) do you know how to get s3 image in this code?

Comment: If you need just the URL of it - you can append filename to the url endpoint of your bucket that you will have stored somewhere like app config. If you need to download it, either do a get request to this url or something like boto's `download_file()` method. Here are the docs for the latter: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to do it.`